# in this sentence passed and held two verb confusing me explain the sentence with grammer of it

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence

The Parliament on the other hand passed held discussions on the The Motor Vehicles (Amendment) Bill which have been carried forward today.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's an error. News reporting is a hectic activity and sometimes errors are liable to creep in.

Comment: If we assume the sentence is as intended, it might be talking about discussions that were “held” (for a later time), saying that the related motions were now “passed” and “carried forward”.

Answer (score -1):

in the above sentence 'held' is used as an adjective of 'discussions' noun......'held' describes which type of 'discussions'.

past participle form of verbs is also used as an adjective (ex. solved examples, broken glass etc.)

Comment: What does “held” (as an adjective) mean?  Can you identify a dictionary that supports such a definition?   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.